# Creating a 100 sqkm KML in Google Earth

Tags: gis, polygon, kml, google-earth

I am trying to create a 100 sqkm (10 km by 10 km) KML square polygon with a point of interest centred right in the middle.

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Xu

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Hi jHilscher, I am very new to Google Earth - I am more proficient with ArcGIS and QGIS but am working with what my new job uses. It was a bit of a rushed job but I basically drew 5km lines from the point of interest upwards, downwards and left and right and subsequently fitting a 4 point polygon to show a square. It's meant more as a visual representation but I want to be able to make proper analyses on the polygon in the future. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

handling polygons in google earth are rather tricky but also there is a lot of thing you can do with that. here's a sample of rather a mature example of a polygon kml file in google earth (it is a ship with very details) and also three link of tutorials that i have watched to creats polygons :
http://www.lynda.com/SketchUp-tutorials/SketchUp-6-Essential-Training/612-2.html?srchtrk=index:1%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq:google%2Bearth%2Bpolygon%0Apage:1%0As:relevance%0Asa:true%0Aproducttypeid:2

http://www.lynda.com/ArcGIS-tutorials/Making-lines-polygons-Google-Earth/162136/186933-4.html

http://www.lynda.com/SketchUp-tutorials/Exporting-models-Google-Earth/612/41758-4.html

and also the kml file :

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiYy-n0k5zKAhVJ1hQKHbqJAVIQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gearthblog.com%2Fblog%2Farchives%2F2012%2F01%2F18%2FCosta%2520Concordia%2520on%2520the%2520rocks.kmz&usg=AFQjCNEhyEKuyKTF5oGds_OAVH3LgqPHpg&sig2=G_sIJeUBosCMZimbirndoQ